# I have Pull the value of ImagelocationID from dropdown through database using foreign key and While creating I got this error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my Controller

```
public async Task <IActionResult> SliderImage(ImageUploadViewModel imageUpload)
{
        string stringFilename = UploadFile(imageUpload);
        var branch = _context.BranchPages.Single(b => b.BranchId == imageUpload.ImageContentPageId);
        var Sliderimage = new ImageContentModel
        {
            ImageOrderNo = imageUpload.ImageOrderNo,
            ImageName = imageUpload.ImageName,
            ImageLocation = imageUpload.ImageLocation,
            RelatedLinks = imageUpload.RelatedLinks,
            Image = stringFilename,
            ImageContentPageId = Convert.ToInt32(branch),
        };
        
        _context.ImageContents.Add(Sliderimage);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return View();
}
```

Error i have got

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'H20_CafeAndPub.Models.BranchPageModel' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
> System.Convert.ToInt32(object value)
> H20_CafeAndPub.Controllers.HomePageController.SliderImage(ImageUploadViewModel imageUpload) in HomePageController.cs + var Sliderimage = new ImageContentModel
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
> System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()

Comment: This `Convert.ToInt32(branch)` is the problem, I would say it's just a mistake and it should be something like `branch.Id`. Currently the code tries to convert an instance of (I guess) `Branch` to an `Int32`. I suppose this object has a property that you should use instead.

Comment: @colinD is correct `branch.BranchId` is what you want there, otherwise if will try to convert the object branch and there is not user or auto conversion available.

Comment: @colinD Your Solution Helped me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the few code like this

**Change 1 :**

var branch = _context.BranchPages.Where(b => b.BranchId == imageUpload.ImageContentPageId).FirstOrDefault();

**Change 2 :**

ImageContentPageId = Convert.ToInt32(branch.Id)